# What is `new object()` used for?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

In F#, we can override `System.Object` methods when creating new object instances with [object expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/object-expressions). This can be very useful when one wants to quickly print with the `ToString()` method:

```
let obj = { new System.Object() with member x.ToString() = "F#" }
printfn "%A" obj
```

However, when should I need to create new objects in C#, beside lock statements?

```
var obj = new object();
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

Comment: I don't know. Have you come across a specific example you'd like to share with us?

Comment: Beside lock statements it's not really useful to instantiate `object`... You can use an `object` instance as a token for comparison but that's about it.

Comment: No, apart from using it as a private synchronization object, AFAIK there is really no use for a runtime `object` typed instance. But that’s true for F# too, the moment you override functionality it stops being an `object` doesn’t it? The only difference is the convenient syntax F# provides.

Comment: @InBetween is right. You can make your own code to get syntax in C# similar to the F# you show. For example with [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4), you can say `var obj = Mock.Of<object>(x => x.ToString() == "F#");` and `var` will stand for `System.Object`, the compile-time type of the mock. Of course the run-time type, as seen with `obj.GetType().ToString()` for example, will be something inheriting from `System.Object`.